# Why blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKeyAsync fails but blobClient.DownloadToAsync succeeds?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to access blob in Azure. I can access it using the blobClient.DownloadToAsync  call as shown in the GetAsync method below. But I cannot access it if I use the blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKeyAsync as shown in the CreateSasTokenUri shown below

```
 public class AppBlobService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public AppBlobService(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    public async Task<Uri?> CreateSasTokenUri(string containerName, string blobName)
    {
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString);
        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
        Uri ret = null;
        try
        {
            if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
            {
                ret = await GetUserDelegationSasBlob(blobClient);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        return ret;

    }
    private async Task<Uri> GetUserDelegationSasBlob(BlobClient blobClient)
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient =
            blobClient.GetParentBlobContainerClient().GetParentBlobServiceClient();

        Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey =
            await blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKeyAsync(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7));

        BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = blobClient.BlobContainerName,
            BlobName = blobClient.Name,
            Resource = "b",
            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
        };

        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read );

        BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(blobClient.Uri)
        {
            Sas = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(userDelegationKey,
                blobServiceClient.AccountName)
        };

        return blobUriBuilder.ToUri();
    }
    public async Task<BlobEntity> GetAsync(string containerName, string blobName)
    {
        var ret = new BlobEntity(containerName, blobName);
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString);
        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
        if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(ms);
            ret.DataStream = ms;
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

The exception that I receive is:

> Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
> ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed
> Additional Information:
> AuthenticationErrorDetail: Only authentication scheme Bearer is supported

How to correctly get a URI to the blob file that the client browser can directly use to read the file?  The blob file is an html whose url will be used in an iframe src property.

Answer (score 0):

GetUserDelegation supports AD Authorization and Azure AD supports Bearer Tokens.

For more information: Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas)

Answer (score -1):

You can generate the URL  by filling in the required data in the following URL

```
https://<storage account name >.blob.core.windows.net/<container name>/<blob name>
```

Also for this to work you will need read access for the blob  just fill the storage account name , container name and blob name in the above URL .

an alternative approach would be to  get the URL  directly from the portal itself.

- Just go to the container tab and select the container where your blob is and click on it

[image]

- Then select and click on the blob whose URL you want

[image]

- Now you can copy the URL from the URL tab

[image]

You can paste the URL directly in the browser

[image]

Comment: There is nothing about a Shared Access Signature (SAS) URI in your response. There is no authorization here.